# Running my symfony project on my host

Tags: php, symfony

I have build a symfony project and uploaded it to my hosting. I want to make it public. I though I just have to use bin/console server:run via SSH, but this isn't the case in production. How do I start my project? When I go to my domain I just get:

```
Forbidden  
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Even though I have controller with route for "/".

Answer (score 1):

It's not such a good idea to use the internal PHP Webserver to run your project in production. Configure Apache or Nginx for your project and you can't start it because your port is used by the apache Webserver which gives you the `Forbidden` error.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand everything on this page. There are config files, but I don't know where to put them. I don't find any apache folders in my hosting. Should I first install it with command?

Comment: That depends on your provider. In most cases if you have a normal webspace you can't edit that files and you have to change that over your webconfig from your provider.

Comment: I think it's working now, but it seem I can only go in /test on my domain, no matter what I do.  It was the by default in the default controller. If I create another controller with view, it givs me a 404 error.